# How to send Lumen logs to ELK

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, lumen

I have a microservice made with Lumen 5.8 and I need to send all the logs to Logstash so that it saves them in ElasticSearch.

I need trying to configure Lumen logging but nothing works well.

I have created a new channel in logging.php called logstash and I'm using Monolog as driver.

```php
'channels' => [
        'logstash' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/lumen.log'),
            'handler' => \Monolog\Handler\SocketHandler::class,
            'handler_with' => [
                'host' => env('LOGSTASH_HOST'),
                'port' => env('LOGSTASH_PORT'),
            ],
        ],
]
```

I have also changed the default channel in the same file:

```php
    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
```

This is my .env:

```
LOG_CHANNEL=logstash
LOGSTASH_HOST=(here I have my Logstash URL)
LOGSTASH_PORT=5055
```

The thing is that I get no errors, but nothing is saved in ElasticSearch.
I'm pretty sure the communication between LogStash and Elastic works, so there must be something wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a tangent, but I've found what works really well for me is running [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) to pick up the logs.

So you would run Lumen/Laravel with the default file-based logging configuration, nothing needed to change there. You would also run Filebeat and configure it to

- know where Logstash is
- know to pick up Laravel/Lumen logs

```
# filebeat config
filebeat.config:
  filebeat.prospectors:
    - type: log
      enabled: true
      paths:
        - /var/www/laravel/storage/logs/*.log
      tags:
        - laravel
        - myAppName
      fields:
        app: myAppName

  output.file:
    enabled: false
  output.logstash:
    hosts: ["logstash.local:5044"]
```

My deployment environment is Kubernetes, so this works really well as 2 containers in one pod, sharing a single `emptyDir` volume.

This does not work for you, if you do not want to run any additional components.

Comment: This will also be more stable if the network or Logstash go down. And if you can log to JSON directly your life will be even easier (Monolog can do that)